# How to get only last two character from current and next year date in aura controller js

Tags: javascript, aura, date

I have used the below code to get current and next year but it's coming as 2021 and 2022 but I only want 21 and 22 from the below code. Please suggest.

```
var today = new Date();
var currentyyyy = today.getFullYear();
var nextyyyy = today.getFullYear()+1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `options` second parameter of `toLocaleDateString` `Date` js method (where first is a locale):

```
const options = {year: '2-digit'};
const today = new Date();
console.log('today year: ', today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));

const nextYear = new Date(today.getFullYear( )+ 1, today.getMonth(), today.getDate());
console.log('next year: ', nextYear.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options));
```

console is:

> today year: 21
>
> next year: 22